# how to ios chat implement with simple mysqlite DB?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, cocoa

I am implementing ios chat application i have client side coding, how to send the text to receiver side using Mysqlite with PHP.

Please assist me.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly sure what you're looking for, but [this](http://www.raywenderlich.com/51127/nsurlsession-tutorial) is a good tutorial introducing you to NSURLSession in iOS 7. That shows you how you can post requests to a web server and deal with data coming back. Handling the request on the server side with PHP is pretty straight-forward; you treat it like you would a normal form.

Comment: thanks for your reply i need Database design and Connection coding for client to server.

Comment: I didn't vote minus. Add comments like this to your own post.

Comment: @Arulnathan this exact what you need - sending requests to server side.